# Proof for $\dim(U+W)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was studying linear algebra today when I got a formula that gives me the dimensions of a sum between two subspaces:
$$
\dim (u+w) = \dim(u) + \dim(w) - \dim(u \cap w)
$$And there's a proof below it... But before reading the proof, I wanted to give it a try... Here's what I've got:

$U$ and $W$ are subspaces.
$t = \dim(U)$ and $s = \dim(W)$

1)My proof for direct sum:

If i have $V =  U\oplus W$, I can assume that $U \cap W = 0$ and for any $z \in V$ it can be written as a linear combination between the vectors of the basis $U$ and $W$:
$$
z = \sum_{i=1}^{t} \beta_{i}\cdot U_{i} + \sum_{i=1}^{s} \gamma_{i}\cdot W_{i} : \forall U_{i} \in U, W_{i} \in W, \beta,\gamma \in R
$$
Because of that two affirmatives, I can assume that the vectors in the basis $U$ and $W$ will be L.I, therefore, will be a basis for $V$, and $V$ will have: $\dim(V) = \dim(U) + \dim(W) = t+s$.

2)My proof for sum with intersection:

Now if I have that $V = U+W$, I can assume that $U \cap W \neq 0 $, and because of that, there are some vectors different than the trivial one, that can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in the basis $U$ and simultaneously as a linear combination fo the vectors in the basis $W$:
$$
z = \sum_{i=1}^{t} \beta_{i}\cdot U_{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{s} \gamma_{i}\cdot W_{i}\\ \forall U_{i} \in U, W_{i} \in W, \beta,\gamma \in R
$$
Now, what I think is the best to be done is to find solutions for $z$ that will give me the set of vectors that are in the intersection of $U$ and $W$.

Having in hands the numbers of vectors in the set $z$, I can see that $U+W$ will give me an L.D set (because it has some intersection $z$), compound of vectors in the basis $U$ and basis $W$, and since I know that this L.D set needs to be L.I to be a basis for V, I need to remove some dependent vectors, that are directly related to the intersection... That's why:
$$
\dim (u+w) = \dim(u) + \dim(w) - \dim(u \cap w)
$$

That's what I've got by my intuition and knowledge at the moment. Please correct me because I know that I'm not being rigorous, and tell me what you think... Am I in the way? Is that a good approach to the real proof?

Thanks

Comment: Your intuition for the case that $U\cap W\neq 0$ is correct, but I would probably try to avoid starting with basis on $U$ and $W$ because what you really need is a basis for $U\cap W$ so that you can show that the formula actually holds (One way would be to construct $U\oplus (W/(U\cap W))$).

Comment: Thank you for commenting!! But is the proof for $ U \oplus W $ correct?

Comment: Yes, you get that the set of vectors composed of a basis for $U$ and a basis for $W$ form a basis for $V$ (important points here being that a basis is a set of linearly *independent* vectors that *span the space*) by the fact that those spaces have trivial intersection, hence. For the general case, the essential challenge is how to achieve that same sort of situation without having the trivial intersection situation to give you a basis for $V$ for free.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the kernel-image theorem (aka rank-nullity theorem), then consider the linear transformation $T: U \times W \to V$ given by $T(u,w)=u+w$ and prove that the image of $T$ is $U+W$ and the kernel of $T$ is $U \cap W$.

Answer (score 0):

To spell out what I am suggesting in my comments, for a *finite dimensional* vector space, $V$, with subspaces $U$ and $W$, such that $V=U+W$, but not necessarily $U\cap W = \{0\}$.

Let $\{b_i\}$ be a basis for $U\cap W$, then, in particular, since $U\cap W$ is a subspace of $U$ we have that $\{b_i\}$ spans a (sub)space of $U$. We construct a basis for $U$ based on the given basis for that (sub)space as follows:

If $\operatorname{span}\{b_i\}\neq U$, then we find a vector $u_1\in U$ which is not in $\operatorname{span}\{b_i\}$, and append it to the set, so we now have $\{b_i,u_1\}$. If this set spans $U$, we are done, other we repeat the above process to obtain a $u_2$. This process is continued until $\operatorname{span}\{b_i,u_j\}=U$, which will happen in *finitely many steps*, since $U$ must be finite dimensional because $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $V$ is finite dimensional (*See note at end*).

Hence the set $\{b_i,u_j\}$ is a basis for $U$. We perform the analogous construction for $W$, obtaining basis $\{b_i,w_k\}$ for $W$. Now the set $\{b_i,u_j,w_k\}$ must span $V$ because every vector in $V$ is a sum of a vector in $U$ with a vector in $W$ and hence can be expressed as a linear combination of the form

$v=\sum_{i\in I} r_ib_i+\sum_{j\in J}s_ju_j+\sum_{k\in K}t_kw_k$

(side note, all of the $s_j$'s or all of the $t_k$'s can be $0$ depending on which of $U$ or $W$ it lives in).

Now we remark that $\dim V=|I|+|J|+|K|$, where $|A|$ denotes cardinality of $A$ (i.e. "size"). We further observe that $\dim U=|I|+|J|$, $\dim W=|I|+|K|$, and $\dim (U\cap W)=|I|$. Therefore, we conclude that

$\dim U+\dim V-\dim(U\cap W)=(|I|+|J|)+(|I|+|K|)-|I|=|I|+|J|+|K|=\dim V$.

Note: I used finiteness of $V$ to construct the basis. For infinite dimensional $V$, this theorem still holds (edit: as long as $\dim(U\cap V)<\dim V$), if you interpret the $+$ and $-$ as cardinal arithmetic operators instead of real number arithmetic operators. But you need to use a different method to get the required basis (or a different approach to proving the theorem altogether).

Comment: You still need to prove that the big set of size $|I|+|J|+|K|$ is linearly independent. Also, there is no minus operator for cardinal numbers.